# connect-mongo autoRemoveInterval does not work correctly

Tags: mongodb, express, session

My code: (with `express.js` and `express-session`)

```
app.use(session({
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db,
    autoRemove: 'interval',
    autoRemoveInterval: 1 // 1 minute (min)
  }),
  secret: 'someSecret',
  name: 'secret',
  genid: ()=>{
     return uuid4();
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: true,
    maxAge: 60*1000 // 1 minute (ms)
  }
}));
```

I have configured `connect-mongo` so that it cleans up expired sessions every minute. The `maxAge` value for cookies is one minute too. But for some reason `connect-mongo` clears the session not exactly after a minute, but after a minute and 20 seconds. It is important for me that `connect-mongo` cleans it exactly in a minute, but I do not understand why he cleans it so late. Sorry for my English. I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the connect-mongo [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo#remove-expired-sessions), it uses a MongoDB TTL index to expire sessions.

The following is from the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#timing-of-the-delete-operation):

> The TTL index does not guarantee that expired data will be deleted immediately upon expiration. There may be a delay between the time a document expires and the time that MongoDB removes the document from the database.

> The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the period between the expiration of the document and the running of the background task.

> Because the duration of the removal operation depends on the workload of your mongod instance, expired data may exist for some time beyond the 60 second period between runs of the background task.

Using the built-in expiry method is only accurate to within a minute or two.  If you need more precision in that operation, you will need to implement that behavior in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I noticed that when the session changes, using `req.session.param = "some value"`, the `expires` value in the database is constantly updated, can this somehow affect? I do not know how to disable the expires update.

Comment: Yes, I just checked that, when I change the session, like: `req.session.param = "somevalue";`, the `expires` value in the database is extended and it affects the delete speed. If the session value is not changed, `expires` are not extended, and deletion is fast. What to do about it? I do not need `expires` to be extended when the session changes.